# Why am I getting a compiler error when using a comparison within an 'if' statement?

Tags: if-statement, compiler-errors, conditional-statements, comparison, operators

I am trying to make a simple rock, paper, scissors program where the CPU chooses a random number between 0 and 2 and compares it with the player's custom input answer and tells whether or not the player lost. I need a way to compare the player and the CPU's answers so that the player can know if they won or not. I figured I would use if statement with comparison like so:

```
if (plAns.plAnswer = 0 && compAns.CPUanswer = 0) {
cout << "Tie"; 
} else if...
```

I get this error though when trying to compile: 42  45  C:\Users\User\Desktop\CIS 246\RPSDriver.cpp [Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You need to use equality checks, which require `==`, not `=` (which is an assignment).  Use `plAns.plAnswer == 0`.

Comment: will try that thank you